# Trying to run 2 Shortcodes but only display 1 other depening on div ID on visitors browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to set up a Wordpress page where it only executes/displays 1 shortcode depending on a div tag found in the users local browser, not server side.

I am aware that shotcodes are executed server side, which I can get done using 'if/else' conditions, but my problem is that the  tag in question is dynamically visable on client side.

So what I am trying to do is run both shortcodes when the page loads, but then hide or show the correct shortcode depending on whether the  tag is found on the page using if/else with javascript/jquery.

I have been reading about it can be done with ajax/javascript, but as a learner I am stuck.

I would appreciate if anyone can point us in the right direction or better still give me a starting point which I can build on.

---

Update : I have managed to get the task done, thanks to a starting point from
@chiliNUT . Anyway below is the solution i used for those if need it in the future.

**HTML**

```
<div id=div1 style=display:none;>
    [some_short_code]
</div>
<div id=div2 style=display:none;>
    [some_other_short_code]
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   window.onload = function () {
       var xfound = document.getElementsByClassName("elementclass");
       if (xfound.length != 0) {
          document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
       }else{
          document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
       }
    };
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript/jquery to look at the tags on the page, and then branch depending on which shortcode to show. Depending on what your theme is, tags might be styled differently or have different attributes. In my theme, all of the tags are in `<a>` tags and have the attribute `rel=tag`, ie., the *bears* tag looks like

```
<a href="/site/wordpress/?tag=bears" rel="tag">bears</a>
```

Lets say I want to show `div1` if there are *bears*, and `div2` if there are *lions*.

**HTML**

```
<div id=div1 style=display:none;>
[some_short_code]
</div>
<div id=div2 style=display:none;>
[some_other_short_code]
</div>
```

**javascript version**

```
    window.onload = function () {
        //get all the a tags
        var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i in tags) {
            //go thru each tag
            var tag = tags[i];
            //does it have rel=tag? if so, its a tag
            if (tag.getAttribute('rel') === "tag") {
            //its a tag
                if (tag.textContent === "bears") {
                    document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
                } else if (tag.textContent === "lions") {
                    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

or in jquery:

**jQuery version**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //look at each a tag that has rel=tag
        $('a[rel="tag"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === "bears") {
                $('#div1').show();
            } else if ($(this).text() === "lions") {
                $('#div2').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the starting point. I have updated the qith the solution i used. Its getting the task done, but if you have any more pointers to improve the code, let me know,

Comment: you're code looks like it gets the job done fine. How are the tags dynamically generated? It seems like when you are loading the post onto your page, you have access to that post's tags, so I'm missing part of the story it sounds like.